Download shiny HTML output as pdf
I am trying to download HTML output from a shiny app as  pdf.  i have an html ui component in my shiny R app in production on RSConnect which i'd like to download as a pdf from the ui. i have an app ready to be troubleshooted, my current app does not work using chrome print. Please, help me, the code is bellow:
# Use Case - provide user the ability to download an html report from web UI to their file server

library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(summarytools)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("out"),
  downloadButton("download_pdf", "Export to PDF")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$out <- renderUI({
    # example data
    y1 <- c("T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "F", "F", "F", "N")
    y2 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "D")
    x3 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    x4 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    x5 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    d <- data.frame(y1, y2, x3, x4, x5)
    
    # summary report to download as a pdf
    df_summary <- dfSummary(d, round.digits = 3, max.distinct.values = 5)
    out        <- print(arrange(df_summary, Variable),
                 headings = FALSE, method = 'render', valid.col = FALSE, footnote = "", bootstrap.css = FALSE)
    
    # Remove unnecessary elements
    out[[3]][[1]][[3]][[2]] <- NULL
    out
  })
  
  # Create a PDF file from the HTML content
  output$download_pdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "my_report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      
      
      
      # code required to convert html to pdf
      # using RSConnect to manage app on Linux Azure
      # may need to create temp file and manage as markdown somehow using www folder with rmd
      

    }
  )
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)



i tried to split into ui.r and server.r  but also it didnt work

What part exactly doesn't work with chrome print? Do you need the entire HTML page? Or are you just trying to save the summary? Is this specific to the results from dfSummary()?

I just want to make the downloading file as pdf, i dont really need the HTML page. I tried chrome_print but its always the same result.
